# Database to get New York City frontages?

Tags: data, spatial-database, united-states

I'm looking for a database that gives the length of frontage of an address or gives the information necessary to calculate this for New York City (NYC) or for another large US city.

So far I haven't been able to find anything like this.

Does anyone know of a data set that would include this information?

Comment: NYC Dept of City Planning http://gis.nyc.gov/doitt/nycitymap/?searchType=AddressSearch&addressNumber=52&street=CHAMBERS%20street&borough=manhattan&infoType&featureTypes=DDC_PROJECTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESRI Shapefiles for New York City

> MapPLUTO merges PLUTO tax lot data with tax lot features from the
>   Department of Finance’s Digital Tax Map (DTM), clipped to the
>   shoreline. It contains extensive land use and geographic data at the
>   tax lot level in ESRI shape file format and dbase table format

*includes **frontage** 
see metadata
http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/pdf/bytes/meta_mappluto.pdf?r=1

```
Bronx (22.7mb)
Brooklyn (55.2mb)
Manhattan(11.8mb)
Queens (65.4mb)
Staten Island (29.9mb)
```

http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/html/bytes/dwn_pluto_mappluto.shtmlE

Comment: I knew it had to be out there. Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: The best way to thank someone is to mark the question as answered and upvote.